# Error when trying to define a new implicit method on List

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I am trying to use the following code to add a method called `newMethod` on the `List` class.

```
implicit class ListCompanionOps(f: List.type) extends AnyVal {
  def newMethod(p: String) = {
    println(p)
  }
}
```

But the compiler complains with the following error:

```
$ scalac test.scala
test.scala:3: error: ListCompanionOps is already defined as (compiler-generated) method ListCompanionOps
implicit class ListCompanionOps(f: List.type) extends AnyVal {
               ^
one error found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It should be:

```
implicit class ListCompanionOps[A](val f: List[A]) extends AnyVal {
```

`List.type` would mean the type of some object called `List`.

Comment: Now I get a different error?
error: `implicit' modifier cannot be used for top-level objects
implicit class ListCompanionOps[A](f: List[A]) {
               ^
one error found

Comment: Yes, that's a very annoying error. You have to put `implicit`s inside something else - not at top level. Unless you are working in the REPL - then it works. But not in a real program.

Comment: Ah, that was the error all allong! It only works with `List.type` but only if I put it inside my `object. Thanks

Comment: Also, I can't extend from AnyVal for some reason